# Resaltar menú horizontal

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando un menú horizontal y quiero que el campo que se haga click se quede en otro color, estoy usando solo html y css. Hasta ahora solamente consigo que cambie de color si sitúo el cursor sobre el campo en cuestión, pero si lo quito, el marcado se pierde. No consigo dar con algún tutorial ni nada parecido que trate este tema, por lo que me sería de gran ayuda su colaboración.

Os adjunto el HTML y CSS

```css
/*Menú horizontal*/
  .menuhorizontal{
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0px auto;
     background-color: ;
     text-align: center;
  }

  .menuhorizontal ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .menuhorizontal ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
 }

   li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

 a {
 padding: 5px;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

 a:hover {
color: red;
}

 li:hover {
  background-color: none;
}

 a:active{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuhorizontal">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Index</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1.html">Quienes Somos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="2.html">Nuestras Actvidades</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Se agradece cualquier tipo de ayuda

Comment: Te comento que no te van a funcionar las pseudo-clases `:active` ni `:visited`, porque con sólo presionar, vas a cambiar de página. Lo más sencillo es crear una clase `.active` que esté activa (valga la redundancia) en cada ítem del menú de la página en cuestión que estás visitando. Esto puede ser tedioso cuando manejas múltiples páginas y un mismo menú, te recomiendo leas sobre incluir un único template en diferentes páginas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada html puse en su respectivo li a un class="active", por lo que se aplicaría el resaltado en el correspondiente campo.

```
<div class="menuhorizontal">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" class="active">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="1.html">Quienes Somos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="2.html">Nuestras Actvidades</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    .menuhorizontal{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .menuhorizontal ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: white;
    }

    .menuhorizontal ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }

    li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }

    a {
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
     }

    a:hover {
    color: red;
     }

    li:hover {
    background-color: none;
     }

    .active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta con el atributo de CSS   `a:active{background-color:green;}`

```css
a:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuhorizontal">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Index</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1.html">Quienes Somos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="2.html">Nuestras Actvidades</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: a:active lo deja de otro color

Comment: a:visited - define el estilo para enlaces visitados
a:active - un enlace se convierte en activo una vez que se hace clic en él
a:hover - ocurre cuando el ratón está sobre el enlace

Comment: puedes intentar: ```.menuhorizontal ul li:active{background:red;} ``` y ```.menuhorizontal ul li:hover{background:red;}```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con la propiedad "visited" de css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

a:link {
  color: red;
}

a:visited {
  color: green;
}

a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}

a:active {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" target="_blank">link</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```